# How can I detect programmatically (e.g.IBAction) when the tab selection changes views?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabcontroller

I am using Swift 5. I would like to be able to programmatically detect when a tab bar item is clicked to select a different ViewController. The ideal situation would be to be able to set an IBAction event for the tab item selection. While I can establish an outlet for the tab bar item, I can't seem to find a way to set an IBAction for the item. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `UITabBarDelegate` or `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

add UITabBarControllerDelegate to your tabBarViewContriller then use this function.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    print("last selected index = \(lastSelectedIndex)") //show last index
    print("selected index = \(selectedIndex)") //show current selection index
}
```

Comment: This lets me know what tab item is/was selected, but I need to know when the new view is in focus. Apparently, didLoad isn't triggered when the view is switched by the tab bar. I have some housekeeping to do when a new view loads, i.e. IBAction wish. This is important (for me) when the user switches back-and-forth with the tab bar. I could use the UITabBarControllerDelegate if there was a way to trigger it.